# What do I need for VLC to play mp4 video?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I'm  trying to set up a Raspberry Pi as a media box that can stream from torrents using [Peerflix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerflix). To test, I've set up a local tracker and one torrent containing an mp4 video. Peerflix is working fine, but VLC closes immediately after opening both streaming and with the local video with the following output:

```
[010750d0] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[b3a0d5b0] freetype spu text error: failed to load font file Serif Bold
LibEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[ad4621a8] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad4621a8] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad4621a8] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad460d00] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad460d00] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad462220] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (2)
[ad461ba8] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[ad460d00] core filter error: Failed to create video filter2
[b4011210] core vout display error: Failed to create video filter2
[b4011210] core vout display error: Failed to adapt decoder format to display
[b3a1e188] freetype spu text error: failed to load font file Serif Bold
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm working with Arch Linux ARM, with Openbox as my window manager. libvdpau is installed and everything is up-to-date. I haven't installed any font libraries but I'm not sure which ones are required here, and don't think it's those errors that are crashing VLC.

Can anyone help figure out what I'm missing? I'm sure it's obvious and I just glossed over something somewhere, but I'm stumped.

EDIT: I installed pulseaudio for good measure. VLC no longer complains about audio, but otherwise is the same.

EDIT 2: After following the [Arch Linux wiki guide for VLC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLC_media_player#Failed_to_open_VDPAU_backend) and installing dri2proto, the error changes to a DRI2 failure message, otherwise the same. Updated accordingly. The only solution I've seen is to install the nouveau drivers, which are only packaged for ARMv7 on Arch Linux ARM. I'm not sure if I'm just doing something wrong or I should try compiling from source.

EDIT 3: Switching to XVideo output will play, but there's no audio and no video. Disabling video does play sound.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at other video options in VLC settings. Try using `xvideo` for output first. `glx` might be worth trying if `xvideo` doesn't work, but I think that's what's causing your problem in the first place. After those two, keep cycling through the list and trying to play your video.

[image: VLC screenshot showing options in Debian]

Though since it's segfaulting, there are so many other things it could be. If all of the above failed, I'd just try compiling it myself.

Comment: Funny enough, I was just trying that. Most settings give similar errors then segfault. XVideo will play audio, but not video. I'll try compiling VLC from source.

Comment: @user1576628 alright! good luck! (and I'm pretty sure it has this, but just in case, make sure you have libx264.)

Comment: Yeah it was installed as a dependency of something. Just to avoid screwing myself I crossposted to the ALARM forums. Audio playback on XVideo is also not working now.

Comment: D: is this with the compiled version?

Comment: Not yet. I didn't have any development tools installed. I'm actually getting compiler errors right now. Fun.

Comment: I did some digging and it looks like VLC doesn't support hardware acceleration on Raspberry Pi. Mucking around with the options didn't fix it. I haven't gotten it working (I decided to give up and use omxplayer because it's all I need), but I did find a guide on doing it at http://intensecode.blogspot.ca/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html.

Comment: ah. If you don't need a UI, btw, try ffplay from the ffmpeg project. Only requires SDL and supports a ton of formats (everything ffmpeg and by extension VLC can).

Comment: fixed crash on Ubuntu by switching from OpenGL Video Output to Automatic